# Tabs with ViewPager - How to get instance and not new object?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using the standard Android [tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and I need to access my tabs from the parent activity.

I do the following in my `MainActivity` to get my tabs:

```
myTab = ((FirstTabFragment)mAdapter.getItem(index));
```

The problem is that I always get a new object and not the instance because the `getItem` is implemented as follows:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Status fragment activity
            return new FirstTabFragment();
        case 1:
            // Mission fragment activity
            return new SecondTabFragment();
        case 2:
            // Team fragment activity
            return new ThirdTabFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
...
```

I googled quite a lot but I still can't find any working solution to get the instance ob my `Fragments`.

I need the instance because I need to alter the fragment's views and therefore I need it's variables.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) with the method [findFragmentById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29) or [findFragmentByTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29). Of course, you need to declare an ID or a TAG for each fragment created by the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. If I remember correctly, the default implementation uses the class name as tag.

Answer (score 0):

Save the fragment in `SparseArray` or in `HashMap`. Add the fragment in array in your `getItem` method also override the `onFragmentDestroy` method. In method  remove the item from `SparseArray` or `HashMap`. Now create a getter method somthing like this

```
  public Fragment getFragment(int pos) {
               return array.get(pos);

}
```